# How to "include" third party modules into my python script to make it portable?

Tags: python

I've developed a little script that searches through a wallpaper database online and download the wallpapers, I want to give this script to another person that isn't exactly good with computers and I'm kinda starting with python so I don't know how to include the "imports" of the third party modules in my program so it can be 100% portable, Is there something that can help me do this? or I will have to enter and analyse my third party modules and copy&paste the functions that I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Worse thing to do

An easy thing you can do is simply bundle the other modules in with your code.  That does **not** mean that you should copy/paste the functions from the other modules into your code--you should definitely **not** do that, since you don't know what dependencies you'll be missing. Your directory structure might look like:

```
/myproject
    mycode.py
    thirdpartymodule1.py
    thirdpartymodule2.py
    thirdpartymodule3/
        <contents>
```

#### Better thing to do

The real best way to do this is include a list of dependencies (usually called `requirements.txt`) in your Python package that Python's package installer, `pip`, could use to automatically download.  Since that might be a little too complicated, you could give your friend these instructions, assuming Mac or Linux:

1. Run `$ curl http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py | python`.  This provides you with tools you'll need to install the package manager.
2. Run `$ curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python`.  This installs the package manager.
3. Give your friend a list of the names of the third-party Python modules you used in your code.  For purposes of this example, we'll say you used `requests`, `twisted`, and `boto`.
4. Your friend should run from command line `$ pip install <list of package names>`.  In our example, that would look like `$ pip install requests twisted boto`.
5. Run the Python code!  The lines like `import boto` should then work, since your friend will have the packages installed on their computer.

Comment: That domain (python-distribute.org) no longer exists. Care to update your answer?

Answer (score 2):

The easi(er) way:

1. Start with a clean [virtual environment](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).
2. Install packages that you need to develop your code.
3. Once you are done, create a [list of requirements](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html#freezing-requirements) for your project.
4. Send this file (from step 3) to your friend.

Your friend simply does `pip install -r thefile.txt` to get all the requirements for your application.

Here's an example:

```
D:\>virtualenv --no-site-packages myproject
The --no-site-packages flag is deprecated; it is now the default behavior.
New python executable in myproject\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools................done.
Installing pip...................done.

D:\>myproject\Scripts\activate.bat
(myproject) D:\>pip install requests
Downloading/unpacking requests
  Downloading requests-0.14.1.tar.gz (523Kb): 523Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests

    warning: no files found matching 'tests\*.'
Installing collected packages: requests
  Running setup.py install for requests

    warning: no files found matching 'tests\*.'
Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...

(myproject) D:\>pip freeze > requirements.txt
(myproject) D:\>type requirements.txt
requests==0.14.1
```

Comment: You should probably note that this assumes Windows.

Comment: It works wherever virtualenv is available (basically, wherever Python is available); it is not Windows specific.

Comment: virtualenv does, but your command line commands are Windows-specific (`type`, `myproject\Scripts\activate.bat`, etc.), and given that this is a question for newbies, I wouldn't want future ones reading to be confused about how to invoke virtualenv.